# Por que Debugger pula linha com header, não indo para o link?

Tags: php, xdebug

Quando inicio o debugger php7.0 CLI com essa configuração do php.ini:

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "path"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_handler= "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000

[CLI Server]
; Whether the CLI web server uses ANSI color coding in its terminal output.
cli_server.color = On
```

O debugger  entra no if e chega em  header('location:login.php'); mas não vai para a pagina login.php. Em vez disso sai da condicional if passando pelos includes chegando até o final do arquivo. 
Não direciona para o " include $fullpath; ".

Vale lembrar que em execução normal o programa funciona entra no login o banco retorna a pesquisa é verificado a veracidade dos dados e então acesso a pagina inicial do programa.Claro que uso o apache que está instalado a parte.

> ( explicando essa parte - eu instalei o Lampp que vem com Mysql, apache e  Proftpd juntos. Na procura por um debuggador achei as instruções para baixar o php5.1 fiz $ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug configurei o php.ini como informado em http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/depuracao-de-aplicacoes-php-com-xdebug/ .
>   Só então percebi que na realidade estou com dois apaches um denominado apache e o outro apache2, se entendi certo. A coisa é que estou com dois php.ini, contudo tomei o cuidado de configurar os dois da mesma forma.)

O que acontece com o caminho ignorado pelo debugger ? Por que ele ignora o caminho do header ?

```
?php
session_start();

if( !(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login']==true) ){
header('location:login.php');
}  


include 'application/dao/Connection.php';
include 'biblioteca/Conversor.php';
include 'biblioteca/Validator.php';

if( isset($_GET['page']) ){
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  $php='';
  $class='';
  $folder='';
  $fullpath='';
if(strpos($page, "_")!= 0){
    $vetor = explode("_", $page);
    $folder = $vetor[0];
    $class = $vetor[1];

}else{
    $file = "";
    $class = "";
} 

$fullpath = "$folder/$class.php";

if(file_exists($fullpath) == false){
    $fullpath = "begin.php";
}   
} else {
  $fullpath = "begin.php";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> O debugger entra no if e chega em header('location:login.php'); mas não vai para a pagina login.php.

Para enteder o real funcionamento, é necessário entender como o `header` funcionar e como ele é tratado.

PHP.net:

> header — Send a raw HTTP header

Basicamente, o `header` envia um cabeçalho HTTP para o browser. O output do cabeçalho nada mais é que texto puro. Grosseiramente falando, é um `echo` específico para cabeçalhos e que ignora o buffer de saída (*output buffer*).

No caso de um cabeçalho com `location`, o que é enviado para o browser é que um direcionamento deve ser executado.

O PHP não sabe executar redirecionamentos, o comando `header('location:login.php')` envia o cabeçalho de redirecionamento para o browser e quem executa o redirecionamento é o próprio browser.

Outro detalhe é que o `header` não interrompe a execução do código. Tanto é que é recomendável utilizar um `die`, `exit` ou `return` logo após o `header`.

```
header('location:login.php');
die();
```

Quando o browser recebe o cabeçalho de redirecionamento, o browser realiza o redirecionamento para você.

> O que acontece com o caminho ignorado pelo debugger ? Por que ele ignora o caminho do header ?

Isso ocorre, também, pelo lugar que você está executando o código.

> Quando inicio o debugger php7.0 **CLI** com essa configuração do php.ini:

Em toda a explicação, eu enfatizei o uso de browser. Todo o redirecionamento é realizado apenas pelo browser.

No seu caso, você está executando seu código via CLI (*commando-line interface*). O PHP CLI não realiza redirecionamentos por não utilizar o protocolo HTTP (protocolo o qual é utilizado pelo browser). Tanto que, o PHP CLI ignora completamento a execução do `header`.

Logo, como a execução do `header` é completamente ignorada e ele não interrompe a execução do script, é normal o *debugger* continuar a execução do código como se nada tivesse acontecido.

> Não direciona para o " include $fullpath; ".

Não localizei no seu código o `include $fullpath`.

Mais informações:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8083152/1628790

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894758/1628790

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932511/1628790

Comment: O include $fullpath está no body. Eu incluo o include do top.php que é onde está o menu. Depois o "corpo" do site e logo a pós o buttom.php que é o rodapé. Basicamente só troco o conteúdo do  meio da pagina do site.

Comment: Só uma coisa. Como testar o site pelo debugger?  Tenho um problema no carregamento de alguns itens e gostaria de debugar todos os passos até chegar na pagina com o problema. Isto é impossível em php ? Em java é molesa da pra andar em todo o código, passo a passo. Já em php ....

Comment: Chamada para onde Gabriel?

Comment: Se refere a botão direito em index.php -> debug as -> php CLI application ?  Segue github se achar por bem ser mais. https://github.com/FabianoSouzaPereira/myschool.com.br

Comment: Acabei viajando aqui, qual IDE você está usando? Faz tempo que não mexo com o xDebugger. Farei uns testes mais tardes para entender o por que.

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

Comment: @FabianodeSouzaPereira desculpe pela demora, mas não consegui encontrar relação entre o xDebug e o problema que você apresenta com o `include`/`require`. Não consegui encontrar nenhuma configuração que pudesse comprometer isso, por isso, acredito que seja a forma (ou IDE) que você está utilizando. Talvez tentar outra, como PHPStorm, NetBean ou ZendStudio para ver se ocorre o mesmo. Como a sua pergunta era mais focada no header, creio que esse seu questionamento possa/deva ser outra pergunta.